# Win64 SSE code compiled for Win32 produces incorrect performance counter result

Tags: winapi, sse, icc

I have a correctly running SSE code that I usually compile for Win64 (I use Intel C++ Compiler 14). This code (consists of SSE intrinsics) after completion also performs a performance counting operation. And I have an issue with this operation when I compile the same code for Win32.

The operation is simple:

```
LARGE_INTEGER Count;
QueryPerformanceCounter( &Count );
uint64_t v = Count.QuadPart;
printf( "%llu\n", v );
printf( "%f\n", (double) v );
```

The first printf prints a correct 64-bit value. Second printf produces -1.#IND00.

If I assign v manually, the error goes away.

The code was checked against possible buffer under/overrun and uninitialized accesses. No idea what's wrong. No such error on Win64.

Compiler produces the following code: on that block:

```
;;; LARGE_INTEGER Count;
;;; QueryPerformanceCounter( &Count );
    lea       eax, DWORD PTR [1408+esp]                     ;152.1
    push      eax                                           ;152.1
    call      DWORD PTR [__imp__QueryPerformanceCounter@4]  ;152.1
                            ; LOE ebx esi
.B1.94:                     ; Preds .B1.93

;;; uint64_t v = Count.QuadPart;
    mov       eax, DWORD PTR [1408+esp]                     ;153.14
    mov       edi, DWORD PTR [1412+esp]                     ;153.14
    mov       DWORD PTR [24+esp], eax                       ;153.14

;;; printf( "%llu\n", v );
    push      edi                                           ;154.1
    push      eax                                           ;154.1
    push      OFFSET FLAT: ??_C@_05A@?$CFllu?6?$AA@         ;154.1
    call      _printf                                       ;154.1
                            ; LOE ebx esi edi
.B1.344:                    ; Preds .B1.94
    add       esp, 12                                       ;154.1
                            ; LOE ebx esi edi
.B1.95:                     ; Preds .B1.344

;;; printf( "%f\n", (double) v ); 
    mov       DWORD PTR [esp], OFFSET FLAT: ??_C@_03A@?$CFf?6?$AA@ ;155.1
    mov       eax, DWORD PTR [24+esp]                       ;155.1
    mov       DWORD PTR [32+esp], eax                       ;155.1
    mov       DWORD PTR [36+esp], edi                       ;155.1
    fild      QWORD PTR [32+esp]                            ;155.1
    shr       edi, 31                                       ;155.1
    fadd      QWORD PTR [_2il0floatpacket.1575+edi*8]       ;155.1
    fstp      QWORD PTR [4+esp]                             ;155.1
    call      _printf                                       ;155.1
```

However, if I duplicate this part after second printf:

```
QueryPerformanceCounter( &Count );
v = Count.QuadPart;
printf( "%f\n", (double) v );
```

The printf prints a correct value.
The assembler code is a bit different though:

```
;;; QueryPerformanceCounter( &Count );
    lea       eax, DWORD PTR [1408+esp]                     ;156.1
    push      eax                                           ;156.1
    call      DWORD PTR [__imp__QueryPerformanceCounter@4]  ;156.1
                            ; LOE ebx esi
.B1.97:                         ; Preds .B1.96

;;; v = Count.QuadPart;
;;; printf( "%f\n", (double) v );
    fild      QWORD PTR [1408+esp]                          ;158.1
    mov       eax, DWORD PTR [1412+esp]                     ;158.1
    shr       eax, 31                                       ;158.1
    mov       DWORD PTR [esp], OFFSET FLAT: ??_C@_03A@?$CFf?6?$AA@ ;158.1
    fadd      QWORD PTR [_2il0floatpacket.1575+eax*8]       ;158.1
    fstp      QWORD PTR [4+esp]                             ;158.1
    call      _printf                                       ;158.1
```

Comment: Can you show a [mcve]

Comment: Looks right to me.  `printf`'s `%f` conversion does take a double, not a float (unlike scanf).  Maybe check the assembly?  Maybe your 32bit code is putting the double in an xmm register, instead of passing on the stack?  The 64bit ABI passes double args in xmm registers, but the 32bit windows and linux ABIs both pass doubles on the stack (and return them on the x87 FP stack).  Maybe it's a compiler bug.

Comment: David Heffernan, it would be easy and not requiring any consulting if I could make such example. Thanks for reading. I'll try to look at assembly - frankly saying, not too much amusing thing to do. Maybe it's time to upgrade compiler, or forget about Win32 architecture.

Comment: Odd.  Does `static_cast<double>(v)` work? It might be giving you `reinterpret_cast` semantics, for some reason.

Comment: Thanks, ... static_cast<double> does not work.

Comment: Maybe SSE mode needs some "switch" to FPU mode which isn't performed by the compiler due to some mistake?

Comment: I can't spot any obvious issues with the generated code. The issue "going away" in a direct cast is an interesting clue though. In that case you're doing converting a signed int64_t as opposed to an unsigned uint64_t, the latter unsupported by the FPU/SSE and faked here with a bit-hack and table. Can you try switching the type of `v` to int64_t, and also stepping through the original assembly and dumping the 16 bytes around the _2il0floatpacket.1575 table? It ought to contain 0 and 2^64 in double-precision floating point, but perhaps something got screwed up along the way.

Comment: doynax, thanks for the ideas. When I use int64_t v = Count.QuadPart; things do not change while the funny "_2il0floatpacket.1575" is not used.

Comment: However, if I duplicate this part, after second printf: QueryPerformanceCounter( &Count ); v = Count.QuadPart; printf( "%f\n", (double) v ); The printf prints a correct value.

Comment: @aleksv: I fear we don't have sufficient information to analyze the problem, something external appears to be tripping up `printf` here (perhaps a stray pointer is messing up the stack, something has twiddled the FPU rounding modes, or in all likelihood something else weird is going on). You will have to sit down and step through the assembly into `printf` (hopefully ICC ships with standard library source) to follow the values and conversion function. Or gradually pair down your code into a minimal repro case. Or both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution: after performing SSE computations the _mm_empty() function should be called.